# Modern Standard Mandarin equivalent of the 倒...不... and 半...不... constructs?

Tags: grammar, mandarin, topolect, synonyms

I've seen this mostly as dialect usage, but I'm wondering if there's a Modern Standard Mandarin (MSM) equivalent.

**倒...不...** - (seemingly) neither A nor B

> 倒男不女
>
> 倒文不武
>
> 倒明不白

**半...不...** - (seemingly) half A not B

> 半死不活
>
> 半大不小
>
> 半生不熟

Do similar constructs exist in MSM?

Comment: `倒...不...` is not common in MSM, while `半...不...` is in both oral and written MSM.

Comment: @halfelf is there an equivalent of `倒...不...`?

Comment: `半..不..` is just the equivalent you need. They have more meaning than `neither nor` or  `half a not b` which is a literal sense. If I say someone looks `半男不女`, I mean he/she looks neither male nor female, and imply that this is disgusting for me.  If I say `半文不武`, means someone is not good in both liberal arts and military arts, and imply that looking down upon this one.  These phrases usually express a negative attitude, contempt or despising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only know [不...不...]  and [半...不] , never heard of [ 倒...不...]

Example:

不男不女 (not a man nor a woman)

半男不女 (not fully a man, not quite a woman)

Comment: I figured both were dialectical in use

Comment: Here in Chengdu, people are used to saying 倒…不…, and it means the same as 半…不… in Mandarin.